# Appium, When i try to swtich from Native to Webview at that time error comes

Tags: android, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, appium, appium-android

when i try to swtich from Native to Webview at that time error comes
**code**
Set contextNames = driver.getContextHandles();
        for (String contextName : contextNames) {
        System.out.println(contextName); //prints out something like NATIVE_APP, WEBVIEW_com.example.android etc..}
        }
        String setContext = contextNames.toArray()[1].toString();
        driver.context(setContext);enter code here`enter code here`

**output**
Session is created
NATIVE_APP
WEBVIEW_com.XX.XXX_App
after error start

```
enter code here
```

Exception in thread "main" io.appium.java_client.NoSuchContextException: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: No Chromedriver found that can automate Chrome '74.0.3729'. You could also try to enable automated chromedrivers download server feature. See https://github.com/appium/appium/blob/master/docs/en/writing-running-appium/web/chromedriver.md for more details
Build info: version: '3.13.0', revision: '2f0d292', time: '2018-06-25T15:32:14.902Z'
System info: host: 'MOHTASIM', ip: '192.168.0.103', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_231'
Driver info: io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver
Capabilities {app: C:\Users\Admin\eclipse-work..., appPackage: com.avanoo.storyApp, autoAcceptAlerts: true, autoGrantPermissions: true, chromeOptions: {w3c: false}, databaseEnabled: false, desired: {app: C:\Users\Admin\eclipse-work..., autoAcceptAlerts: true, autoGrantPermissions: true, chromeOptions: {w3c: false}, deviceName: Nexus_S_API_29, platformName: android, unicodeKeyboard: true}, deviceApiLevel: 29, deviceManufacturer: Google, deviceModel: Android SDK built for x86, deviceName: emulator-5554, deviceScreenDensity: 240, deviceScreenSize: 480x800, deviceUDID: emulator-5554, javascriptEnabled: true, locationContextEnabled: false, networkConnectionEnabled: true, pixelRatio: 1.5, platform: LINUX, platformName: Android, platformVersion: 10, statBarHeight: 36, takesScreenshot: true, unicodeKeyboard: true, viewportRect: {height: 764, left: 0, top: 36, width: 480}, warnings: {}, webStorageEnabled: false}
Session ID: 212580e7-809c-44f2-9b04-204a81695f36
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.context(AppiumDriver.java:231)
    at Avanoo.Emulator_test.main(Emulator_test.java:55)

Comment: It's really hard to read, please follow our formatting guidelines so people here at Stackoverflow can begin helping you. See description: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 0):

If I can properly see in your question, the latest exception is the following: 
***No Chromedriver found that can automate Chrome '74.0.3729'.***

This just means your ChromeDriver is of lower version than you Chrome browser, which ain't gonna work. Download the same or simply the latest version of chrome driver.

P.S. If you already have a later version of ChromeDriver but Appium refuses to reckognize it, start appium server with following command:

```
appium --chromedriver-executable C:/path-to-your-chromedriver/chromedriver.exe
```